# Хранение спрайтов в gamedev

Tags: разработка-игр

Я начал заниматся разработкой игр довольно недавно, и у меня один вопрос, дело в том что игра (мое понимание) это одна большая картинка которая зависит от математики игры, и у меня стоит вопрос, где хранить картинки спрайтов: в объектах (например игрок), или в main показывать картинку в зависимости от состояния объекта? Что используют в больших проектах?

Answer (score 0):

В больших проектах их загружают из диска, либо же если картинок мало то с интернета, но в основном все таки с диска, и если часто используеться то можно в оперативке держать.